# Postgres key-value table, select values as columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have the following table:

```
+----+---------+-------+
| id |  Key    | Value |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 | name    | Bob   |
|  1 | surname | Test  |
|  1 | car     | Tesla |
|  2 | name    | Mark  |
|  2 | cat     | Bobby |
+----+---------+-------+
```

`Key` can hold basically anything. I would like to arrive at the following output:

```
+----+------+---------+-------+-------+
| id | name | surname |  car  |  cat  |
+----+------+---------+-------+-------+
|  1 | Bob  |  Test   | Tesla |       |
|  2 | Mark |         |       | Bobby |
+----+------+---------+-------+-------+
```

Then I would like to merge the output with another table (based on the `id`).

Is it possible to do, if I don't know what the `Key` column holds? Values there are dynamic.
Could you point me to the right direction?

Comment: Don't do it in SQL, do it in your application when you *display* the data. Or change the key/value pairs in a single row and a `jsonb` column rather than in multiple rows.

Comment: I can't in the app. It's for creating a view that then needs to be queried with postgREST. Apps are legacy so I need to provide data in a certain format:(

Comment: PostgREST returns JSON anyway, so you could simply turn those key/value pairs into a single JSONB value in your view.

Comment: @idetyp . . . If your app is querying a table, then it should be expecting a certain set of columns.  That means that the keys are not arbitrary.